# variables in macros

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a Macro to insert data from specific text files from a specific drive, (browleft.txt  from K:...etc) however I would like to be able to have the Macro read from the drive and folder that the excel worksheet is in, and also from a text file with a variable name but the same ending, such as alexbrowleft.txt or grahambrowright.txt etc... is this possible and could anyone help me out... here is the Macro below....

```
Sub insert()
'
' insert Macro
' insert
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+i
'
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "left brow"
    Range("B4").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;K:\browleft.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("$B$4"))
        .Name = "browleft_8"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "right brow"
    Range("B6").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;K:\browright.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("$B$6"))
        .Name = "browright_8"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("A8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "eye left"
    Range("B8").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;K:\eyeleft.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("$B$8"))
        .Name = "eyeleft_8"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "right eye"
    Range("B10").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;K:\eyeright.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("$B$10"))
        .Name = "eyeright_8"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("A12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "jaw"
    Range("B12").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;K:\jaw.txt", Destination _
        :=Range("$B$12"))
        .Name = "jaw_8"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("A14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "mouth height"
    Range("B14").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;K:\mouthheight.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("$B$14"))
        .Name = "mouthheight_8"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("A16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "mouth width"
    Range("B16").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;K:\mouthwidth.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("$B$16"))
        .Name = "mouthwidth_8"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("A18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "nostrils"
    Range("B18").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;K:\nostrils.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("$B$18"))
        .Name = "nostrils_9"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("17:17,15:15,13:13,11:11,9:9,7:7,5:5").Select
    Range("A5").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Left Brow"
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Right Brow"
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Eye Left"
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Eye Right"
    Range("A8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Jaw"
    Range("A9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Mouth Height"
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Mouth Width"
    Range("A11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Nostrils"
    Range("A12").Select
End Sub
Sub deletedata()
'
' deletedata Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 23
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 30
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 35
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 40
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 46
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 52
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 58
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 62
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 67
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 71
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 75
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 79
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 83
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 86
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 90
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 94
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 98
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 103
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 107
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 111
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 116
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 120
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 124
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 129
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 133
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 138
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 142
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 146
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 149
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 153
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 156
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 163
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 170
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 176
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 181
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 187
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 193
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 199
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 204
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 208
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 211
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 214
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 216
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 218
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 219
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 221
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 222
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 223
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 224
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 225
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 226
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 227
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 228
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 229
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 230
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 231
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 233
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 234
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 236
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 238
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 240
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 243
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 244
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 247
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 248
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 250
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 252
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 253
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 254
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 255
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 256
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 257
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 258
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 256
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 252
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 232
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 223
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 214
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 204
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 196
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 186
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 176
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 166
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 157
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 148
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 141
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 135
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 130
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 125
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 120
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 116
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 112
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 109
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 108
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 107
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 105
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 103
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 101
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 99
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 97
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 94
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 91
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 88
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 86
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 83
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 81
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 79
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 78
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 77
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 76
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 75
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 74
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 72
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 71
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 70
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 69
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 68
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 67
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 66
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 65
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 64
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 63
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 62
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 60
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 58
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 56
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 52
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 50
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 46
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 43
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 40
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 38
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 37
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 36
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 35
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 34
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 35
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 41
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 44
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 47
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 52
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 58
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 64
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 70
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 77
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 86
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 97
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 106
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 116
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 124
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 131
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 138
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 144
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 150
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 156
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 161
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 167
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 173
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 180
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 188
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 195
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 202
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 209
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 215
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 221
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 227
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 233
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 239
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 245
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 250
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 254
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 258
    Range("B4:JZ11").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 257
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 252
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 242
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 237
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 232
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 227
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 221
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 214
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 207
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 200
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 182
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 172
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 162
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 152
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 144
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 134
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 125
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 118
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 111
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 105
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 99
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 92
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 86
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 80
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 75
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 70
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 65
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 60
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 56
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 52
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 48
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 44
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 41
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 38
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 34
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 30
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 26
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 23
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 17
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Rows("4:11").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
Sub refresh()
'
' refresh Macro
' refresh values
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
    Range("E4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='OSC '!RC[-3]"
    Range("E4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E4:JZ4"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("E4:JZ4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E4:JZ11"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("E4:JZ11").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 258
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 253
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 246
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 235
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 227
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 218
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 200
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 193
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 186
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 180
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 174
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 169
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 163
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 157
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 152
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 146
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 141
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 135
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 131
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 125
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 120
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 114
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 103
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 98
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 92
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 86
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 81
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 75
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 71
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 66
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 61
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 57
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 54
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 52
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 49
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 48
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 46
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 44
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 41
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 39
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 36
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 32
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 28
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 24
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 21
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 18
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 13
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the path to the workbook that contains the `insert()` macro you can use the following and combine it with the file name.

To get the path to the directiory the file is in, use:

```
ThisWorkbook.Path
```

To get the full path including filename, use:

```
ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

Example:

```
Dim sFilePath as String
Dim sName as String

sName = "alex"
sFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sName & "browleft.txt"

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & sFilePath, _
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand where ThisWorkbook.Path fits in, also the variable is unknown so it cant be assigned.

Comment: It's a readonly property of the workbook you run the code in, so it can never be assigned. You were asking for _the drive and folder that the excel worksheet is in_ - you will find it in `ThisWorkbook.Path`.

Answer (score 0):

With a *bit* of light on making things dynamic.

If you want to make the process a *little* dynamic, you could infact have a cell that contain the file path/name and point your macro to read from that cell :) So you do not have to always go into the macro to change file names.

Plus in that case, you can read your input text files from anywhere in your hard drive - do not need to remember, simply copy paste that full path/file name into the cell :)

Secondly, you can have another cell to specify the the file name that should be `LIKE` xyz or yzx... using a **regex** . That could add more complications, so I am leaving it aside as simplicity is the key here.

Please take a look at the following sample.

File name is `browleft.txt`.
Assume that your file full path is in cell "A2". e.g. `K:\`
You may leave this "A2" cell empty, if you wish to search for the text file in the same folder as your application file. (This Excel work file)
Put your File name in "A3" = `brownleft.txt`
Wildcard string that name should look `LIKE` = `alex`
Put that in cell "A4"

```
Dim strFilePath as String
Dim strFileName as String
Dim strWildCard as String
Dim rngPath as Range
Dim rngName as Range

set rngPath = Range("A2")
set rngName = Range("A3")
set rngWild = Range("A4")

'--- Validate your inputs before processing


If Trim(rngWild.value) <> "" Then
  strWildCard = Trim(rngWild.value)
Else
  strWildCard = "alex" '--- the default wildcard string
End If

If Trim(rngName.value) <> "" Then
  strFileName = Trim(rngName.value)
Else
  strFileName = "brownleft.txt" '--- the default file name
End If

If Trim(rngPath.value) <> "" Then
  strFilePath = Trim(rngPath.value) & strWildCard & strFileName
Else
  strFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strWildCard & strFileName
    End If

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;strFilePath, _
    ...
..
```

Rest follows :)